# Show popup when the browser closes

Tags: php, javascript

popup when the browser closes

I am using onbeforeunload event

```
<script>
function showPopup()
{

  urlstring = "http://www.mydomain.com/popup.php";
            window.open(urlstring,'mywin',"height=400px,width=500px,status=no,toolbar=no");

}



</script> 

<body onbeforeunload="showPopup(); ">
```

but it also show popup when ever I hit back space and page refresh.

**I want show popup only when browser close and not show when  hit back space.**

but it shows all conditions.

Please suggest me any other solution for this.

Comment: Do you want to show a popup when they navigate to a different domain, or when the browser closes, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , here's the bitter truth...

`onbeforeunload` is fired on page refresh and browser close.

The `onbeforeunload` event is fired every time the page is about to unload.

Which includes

1. Clicking on a link
2. Submitting a form
3. Closing the browser(or tab)
4. Refreshing the page

You might find this helpful
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-36808.html

Answer (score 3):

This is showing a popup every time because the onbeforeunload event is not aware of the domain you are leaving, it is only aware of the current page unloading for a new one.

Comment: That is OP already know what is difference b/w OP's question and your answer. This is not answering the question at all.

Comment: @Singh no idea what you are trying to say here but I think it answers the question appropriately. @infotekka is saying that the onbeforeunload is not the appropriate method for what Pradeep is trying to do.

Comment: @a.stgeorge He asked How to do not Why it is happening and answer is all about why it is happening

Comment: @Singh ok here is how you do it, have the desired action fire on this JavaScript event handler "window.onunload"

Comment: @Infotekka onunload event call only browser close and not call page refresh  .  at this time is called both condition

Comment: Ok then I'm sorry but I'm confused, I thought what you wanted was an event that only fires when the browser closes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
    function showPopup(){
        urlstring = "http://www.mydomain.com/popup.php";
        window.open(urlstring,'mywin',"height=400px,width=500px,status=no,toolbar=no");
    }

    window.onunload= showPopup();
    </script>
```

Note: This is DOM Level 0. Not part of any standard

EDITED: Note Infotekka's link to the document.onunload will also work appropriately for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Your page, including its events, is not aware of other tabs, other pages or the browser itself for that matter. It also doesn't know why it is unloaded. The onunload event is the closest you will get, but it fired everytime when your page is unloaded, so also on navigation.

Comment: good point this onunload event will fire everytime the page is unloaded not just closed, i.e. clicking an internal link or as Golez said a navigation item within the site.